# Не компилируется код с async на .net 4

Tags: .net

Нужно чтобы код с `async` работал на XP.

Поставил .NET Framework 4.0 (with KB2468871) и `nuget.exe install Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. [Вот мануал](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203054052/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx?)

Выдает

```
>Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Program.cs
Program.cs(16,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: А какая студия? Или вы компилируете вручную?

Comment: Вручную и в SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

Для компиляции исходников, использующих `async/await`, под .NET Framework 4.0, нужно две вещи:

- Установленный пакет `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. У вас он есть.
- Компилятор C# 5.0 (входит в состав Visual Studio 2012 и старше,
  например). К сожалению, этот компилятор входит только в состав .NET Framework 4.5, который нельзя установить на Windows XP.

Главное не путать конфигурацию машины, на которой вы собираетесь запускать приложение (Windows XP, .NET Framework 4.0) с конфигурацией машины, на которой происходит сборка (.NET Framework 4.5+, Windows 7+, VS 2012+, project target -- .NET Framework 4.0, Microsoft.Bcl.Async). На машине с конфигурацией Windows XP, .NET Framework 4.0 такой код не собрать.

Comment: А-а, блин, там студия 12 под 5-й фреймверк требуется. А 4.5 не пойдет?

Comment: @SmitJohnth обновил ответ. (А "5-го фреймворка" нет в природе. Есть версия фреймворка 4.5 и версия языка C# (и компилятора) 5.0.)